# How to draw a barometer like widget in Android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-canvas

I am trying to develop a few widgets for my application that look like the image below. I am not sure what to use for developing these. OpenGL or Android Canvas or a charting library like AiCharts

Could someone point me in the right direction? 
 [image: Barometer like widgets]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did view like this.

[image]

And can give you my code, but I did it so long time ago that code may be is not so good))

```
public class Tachometer extends View {
    public static final String TAG = Tachometer.class.getSimpleName();

    private Bitmap tachometer;
    private Bitmap arrow;

    private float rotateDegree = 0;
    private float currentValue = 0;
    private float pxDp = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.one_dp);

    private static final float MB = 1024;
    private static final float FIRST_RATE = MB / 105;
    private static final float SECOND_RATE = MB * 9 / 105;
    private static final float MIN_SPEED = 0;
    private static final float MAX_SPEED = MB * 10;


    public Tachometer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initTachometer();
    }

   public Tachometer (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initTachometer();
    }

    private void initTachometer () {
        Options opt = new Options();
        opt.inScaled = true;
        tachometer = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.tachometer_custom, opt);
        arrow = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.arrow_custom , opt);
        setStartPosition();
        this.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(rotateDegree, arrow.getWidth() / 2, arrow.getHeight() - 7.5f*pxDp);
        matrix.postTranslate((tachometer.getWidth()/2) - (arrow.getWidth()/2), 25*pxDp);

        drawRegion_1(canvas, initRed());
        drawRegion_2(canvas, initOrange());
        drawRegion_3(canvas, initYellow());
        drawRegion_4(canvas, initGreen());

        canvas.drawBitmap(tachometer, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(arrow, matrix , null);
    }

    public void update (float value) {
        if (value < MIN_SPEED) update(MIN_SPEED); else
            if (value > MAX_SPEED) update(MAX_SPEED); else {
                if (value < MB ) {
                    rotateDegree = (value / FIRST_RATE) - 105 ;
                } else {
                    rotateDegree = ((value - MB) / SECOND_RATE);
                }
            }
        currentValue = value;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    private void setStartPosition () {
        update(MIN_SPEED);
    }

    private void drawRegions (Canvas canvas , float startConer , float mainConer , int color) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        RectF rect = new RectF();

        rect.set((getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.left) - (getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.x37_5_dp))),
                ((getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.top) - (getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.x37_5_dp)))),
                ((getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.right) + (getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.x37_5_dp)))),
                ((getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.bottom) + (getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.x37_5_dp))))); 

        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.stroke_width));
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawArc(rect, startConer, mainConer, false, paint);
    }

    private void drawRegion_1 (Canvas canvas , int color) {
        drawRegions(canvas , 163f , 60f , color);
    }

    private void drawRegion_2 (Canvas canvas , int color) {
        drawRegions(canvas , 163f+60f , 47f , color);
    }

    private void drawRegion_3 (Canvas canvas , int color) {
        drawRegions(canvas , 165f+63f+42f , 44f , color);
    }

    private void drawRegion_4 (Canvas canvas , int color) {
        drawRegions(canvas , 163f+63f+42f+46f , 62f , color);
    }

    private int initRed () {
        float piece = MB / 8; //~128kb/s

        if (currentValue == 0) return getResources().getColor(R.color.transpert); else 
            if (currentValue < piece) return getResources().getColor(R.color.red_75); else
                if (currentValue < piece * 2) return getResources().getColor(R.color.red_50); else
                    if (currentValue < piece * 3) return getResources().getColor(R.color.red_25); else
                        return getResources().getColor(R.color.red);

    }

    private int initOrange () {
        float piece = MB / 8;//~128kb/s

        if (currentValue < piece * 4) return getResources().getColor(R.color.transpert); else 
            if (currentValue < piece * 5) return getResources().getColor(R.color.orange_75); else
                if (currentValue < piece * 6) return getResources().getColor(R.color.orange_50); else
                    if (currentValue < piece * 7) return getResources().getColor(R.color.orange_25); else
                        return getResources().getColor(R.color.orange);

    }

    private int initYellow () {
        if (currentValue < MB) return getResources().getColor(R.color.transpert); else 
            if (currentValue < MB * 2) return getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow_75); else
                if (currentValue < MB * 3) return getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow_50); else
                    if (currentValue < MB * 4) return getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow_25); else
                        return getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow);

    }

    private int initGreen () {
        float piece = MAX_SPEED / 9; //~1.2 Mb/sec
        float fiveMb = MB * 5;

        if (currentValue < fiveMb) return getResources().getColor(R.color.transpert); else 
            if (currentValue < fiveMb + piece) return getResources().getColor(R.color.green_75); else
                if (currentValue < fiveMb + piece * 2) return getResources().getColor(R.color.green_50); else
                    if (currentValue < fiveMb + piece * 3) return getResources().getColor(R.color.green_25); else
                        return getResources().getColor(R.color.green);

    }
}
```

There are 4 sectors (red, orange, yellow, green) and depends on state colors can be transperent. Try to look at code. It can be helpful for you.

Good luck!

Comment: Wow, thanks. Let me have a go at this.

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17736801/testTachometera.rar look at this project. It has all resources and sample for test view.

Comment: (Posted by a new user that cannot comment yet):  @user3367121 wrote: Is it possible to download test project? The drop box link doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have it now. Sorry.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to create http://i.stack.imgur.com/OIZkM.jpg type of layout in android?